# Install cx_oracle on a portable version of Django?

Tags: python, django, portability, cx-oracle

I am attempting to do this in a portable version of Django:

```
from django.db import load_backend
myBackend = load_backend('django.db.backends.oracle') # or 'mysql', 'sqlite3', 'oracle'
```

However, this results in an error: `Error loading cx_Oracle module: No module named cx_Oracle`. I assumed this just means that `cx_oracle` wasn't installed. When I did a `pip install cx_oracle` (same as I have for other modules needed), it results in this error:

```
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "<string>", line 14, in <module>
      File "e:\PortableDjango\development\tools\virtualenvs\test_djangoproj\build\cx-Oracle\setup.py", line 132, in <module>
        raise DistutilsSetupError("cannot locate an Oracle software " \
    distutils.errors.DistutilsSetupError: cannot locate an Oracle software installation

    Complete output from command python setup.py egg_info:
    Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<string>", line 14, in <module>
  File "e:\PortableDjango\development\tools\virtualenvs\test_djangoproj\build\cx-Oracle\setup.py", line 132, in <module>
    raise DistutilsSetupError("cannot locate an Oracle software " \
distutils.errors.DistutilsSetupError: cannot locate an Oracle software installation

----------------------------------------

Command python setup.py egg_info failed with error code 1 in e:\PortableDjango\development\tools\virtualenvs\test_djangoproj\build\cx-Oracle

Exception information:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "e:\PortableDjango\development\tools\virtualenvs\test_djangoproj\lib\site-packages\pip-1.1-py2.7.egg\pip\basecommand.py", line 104, in main
    status = self.run(options, args)
  File "e:\PortableDjango\development\tools\virtualenvs\test_djangoproj\lib\site-packages\pip-1.1-py2.7.egg\pip\commands\install.py", line 245, in run
    requirement_set.prepare_files(finder, force_root_egg_info=self.bundle, bundle=self.bundle)
  File "e:\PortableDjango\development\tools\virtualenvs\test_djangoproj\lib\site-packages\pip-1.1-py2.7.egg\pip\req.py", line 1009, in prepare_files
    req_to_install.run_egg_info()
  File "e:\PortableDjango\development\tools\virtualenvs\test_djangoproj\lib\site-packages\pip-1.1-py2.7.egg\pip\req.py", line 225, in run_egg_info
    command_desc='python setup.py egg_info')
  File "e:\PortableDjango\development\tools\virtualenvs\test_djangoproj\lib\site-packages\pip-1.1-py2.7.egg\pip\__init__.py", line 256, in call_subprocess
    % (command_desc, proc.returncode, cwd))
InstallationError: Command python setup.py egg_info failed with error code 1 in e:\PortableDjango\development\tools\virtualenvs\test_djangoproj\build\cx-Oracle
```

I assume that it is looking for the Oracle client, which I have in place and is in the PATH variable. What else have I over looked, or what is the best way to get Oracle support in a portable version of Django?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to modify `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` to point to the Oracle client libraries (the `lib` directory) or for Windows - download the [appropriate windows binary](http://cx-oracle.sourceforge.net/).